# Laravel's model::all() method is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

When I try to return Example::all() I get a blank white screen and no errors. If I return Example::with('id') I get all 15102 records in the database.

Has anyone ran into this before? I'm at a loss as to why/how it's not working for this one particular model.

My Model is defined in models/Example.php as

```
<?php

class Example extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'example';

}
```

Comment: can you paste you Model code here, to see it.

Comment: Use `get()` instead of `all()`.

Comment: @Marwelln get() actually returns nothing. The webpage errors out if I use that. I was under the impression get() was only used after a query, like Model::where(where_query)->get(); Plus, this still wouldn't solve the issue I'm experiencing with all();

Comment: What does your debug code look like? How are you determining the results of `Example::all()` and `Example::with('id')`. For reference, the `get()` and `all()` methods are going to return a collection, whereas the `with()` method is going to return a `Builder` object.

Comment: I'm just dumping to the screen with var_dump and/or print_r. all() gives me absolutely nothing. Just a blank white screen, no errors, nothing in the log. I do have all() working a little now, however. I have to specify which fields to pull. If I don't pass anything it fails. Right now I'm requesting 6 fields and it's working. I believe this is just a matter of there being too much data returned.

Answer (score 2):

I think `Model` might be a reserved class name in Laravel, there is an abstract class for it:

http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

Try naming your model file name and class to something else.

Comment: Funny thing is, by extending Eloquent, the OP is actually extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, since `Eloquent` is only an alias for that class.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that it's not actually called Model, that was just for illustration purposes. I updated the question to resolve any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience I have noticed that sometimes it looks like it hasn't done anything but it has. I have the following code in one of my projects:

```
    $homeslides = Home::all();
    foreach ($homeslides as $object) {
        $model['image'] = 'images/fullview/'.$object->image;
        $model['title'] = '<h2>'.$object->title.'</h2>';
        $model['thumb'] = 'images/thumbview/'.$object->thumbnail;
        $model['url'] = URL::to('models/'.$object->id);
        $models[] = $model;
    }
```

If I dd($models) I get the desired result but when I dd($homeslides) I got really worried.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has answered your question. I got the same behaviour and this is as you guessed a matter of "too many results".

I don't know why no error is logged (default in storage/logs/laravel.log or displayed to the user in debug mode), it would be the expected behaviour.

As far as I got thousands of results, I just performed a "limit" on my model and that works perfectly (Laravel 8).

```
$results = Example::limit(100)->get();
```